# how do I pass a variable in app.js down to a route file?

Tags: node.js, express

so my folder structure looks like this:

```
app.js
----routes
    |----user.js
----models
    |----index.js
    |----(all my model files)
```

I want to require all my model files in the app.js file and then pass that variable to the routes as I require them. My thinking was that if any of my route files ever change location I would only need to update app.js instead of also having to update the route file require call.

I know that you can say:

```
var User = require("./routes/user")(db);
app.use('/user', User);
```

my user files however looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

...some code

modules.export = router;
```

I realize that usually you'd write:

```
modules.export = (db)=>{
    some code here...
}
```

this may be a stupid question but how do you modify that to work with the router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My thinking was that if any of my route files ever change location I would only need to update app.js instead of also having to update the route file require call.

If that is your concern, may I interest you in [module aliasing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias)? You can set the path to your module in your `package.json` and then reference them in your route files using the alias you create for them. If the path changes, you would just have to change the path in your `package.json` and not in each file. Module aliasing is also great from getting around referencing files like this ---> `./../../../module.js`

Answer (score 0):

You can put a tiny bit of middleware code near the top of your http.js module, definitely before mounting your router handlers, like this.

```
app.use( function ( req, res, next ) {
  req.models = {};
  req.models.model1 = whatever;
  req.models.model2 = whatelse;
  req.models.other = thing;  /* etc */
  next();
} );
```

Then, when your requests arrive at your routes, they'll have that custom `models` object attached to them for use by route code.